# highly available storage over infiniband: what other than mdraid?

Tags: storage-area-network, infiniband

is mdadm over infiniband a bad idea?
what is the real trick to get reasonable performing storage to survive a single machine failure?

We have been running ceph for a few years now and its *great* for easy (ish) redundancy, but its performance is eye watering. NVMEs easily get to 3GB/s, while our ceph is doing 100MB/s over 50Gbs network while consuming 64 core CPUs. I just don't think i made the right choice here for the performance expectations.

Infiband seems extremely cost effective in comparison with used previous gen 100gb cards costing less than a 50GB ethernet card. It seems very easy and well performing to just expose a local disk over infiniband to another host using iSER.

Now the naive solution to making this survive host failure would be mdraid over multiple remote targets. But i haven't found many people actually doing that and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/448408/216387) is indicating this might even be a bad idea, since mdraid has no understanding of an underlying device being remote. Also [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1931610#c2) makes it clear that this setup will likely run into edge case bugs.

But how else would you build an infiniband storage network in a way that recovers from node failure unattended?

Comment: When I see Infiniband and storage on the same question I got nervous about data at rest. We usually use RDMA for high performing storage, but for scratch, not for permanent storage, but that's our case. There's a ton of solutions, but CEPH is not RDMA friendly, BeeGFS in other hand is. CEPH is slow if we are talking the RDMA world. What exactly you want/need to achieve? When you say host failure it's including the disks? You can use shared SAS backplanes to achieve HA. Parallel filesystems like BeeGFS and LUSTRE does that.

Comment: this is the backend of VM disks (qemu). The setup needs to survive both disk failure (as mdraid would) and failure of an entire node. automatically rescheduling VMs is easy, but storage not so much. Ceph can do this, but at an unacceptable performance loss.

BeeGFS looks great but appears to cost around 300Eur per month, so that's significantly more expensive than just buying a hardware solution. But which one do i want?

Is infiniband the wrong thing to look at, because as you said, it's not usually used for storage?

Answer (score 0):

The go-to solution for IB storage is currently [Lustre](https://www.lustre.org/) and also check out the info in [whamcloud](https://wiki.whamcloud.com/)

Lustre is a distributed filesystem supporting classic raid semantics across servers.
A basic minimalist setup of lustre would consist of a metadata server (MDS) which doubles as also a management server (MGS) and some object storage servers (OSS). Do note that Lustre used the term 'object' long before S3 and what is published is a POSIX-like file system, not an object store.

Comment: Do you have real-world numbers for Gen3+ PCIe drives? What sort of expertise is required to maintain such network with less unplanned outage than just sticking with a Single Point Of this-machine-better-not-Fail?

Comment: I did "community Lustre"  installation for a university about 10 years ago. My current experience is with a much larger setup backed by paid support from DDN. This is with 200Gb cards. You will require dedicated expertise in setting it up, and some expertise in IB which you should already have.

Comment: @anx Can't answer regarding the cost of corrupted data (or unplanned outage) which might result from SPOF setup, but it might take you a couple of days to setup a basic installation from scratch, compared to a couple of hours setting up a netapp box. Don't be afraid to tear down and start from scratch a few time. I ended up taking a week and over 10 retries to get both the performance and redundancy required in the uni setup.